# React/Redux passing variables down to children yields objects instead of strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

New to this.

I am passing props down through children and to children below that and what should be a string being passed down ends up becoming an object. Here is my code.

**Main container**

```
return (
  <div className="row">
      <TableHeaders onSortByChange={this.handleSortBy}
        onSortDirectionChange={this.handleSortDirection}
        query={query}
        sortDirection={sortDirection}
        sortBy={sortBy}
        currentPage={currentPage}
      />...
```

**Child container of main container**

```
export const TableHeaders = (props) => {
  const { onSortByChange, onSortDirectionChange, sortDirection, sortBy } = props;
  ...
  <span onClick={() => onSortByChange({onSortByChange:'ClientNumber', onSortDirectionChange: 'Ascending'})}>Client # </span>
  ...
     {sortBy === "ClientNumber" && <span>
          <GlyphiconDirectionChange onSortDirectionChange={onSortDirectionChange} 
            sortDirection={sortDirection}
            sortBy={sortBy}/>
        </span>}...
```

**Child of the Child container**
(simply shows one line based on whether its "Ascending" or "Descending")

```
const GlyphiconDirectionChange = (props) => {
  const { onSortDirectionChange, onSortByChange, sortDirection, sortBy } = props
    console.log('GlyphiconDirectionChange() sortBy and sortDirection!', sortBy, sortDirection)
  return (
    <span>
      {sortDirection === 'Ascending' ?
          <span onClick={() => onSortDirectionChange({onSortDirectionChange:'Descending', onSortByChange: {sortBy}})} className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt'></span>
        :
          <span onClick={() => onSortDirectionChange({onSortDirectionChange:'Ascending', onSortByChange: {sortBy}})} className='glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes'></span>
      }
    </span>
  )
}
```

**Functions being used in main container**
The two functions referred to above - onSortByChange and onSortDirectionChange.
These are in the main parent container at the moment.

```
    handleSortBy = (values) => {
    const { sortBy, sortDirection, query} = this.props
    values.onSortByChange = values.onSortByChange
    values.onSortDirectionChange = values.onSortDirectionChange
    const searchParams = {
      query,
      sortBy,
      sortDirection,
      ...values,
      currentPage: 1,
    }
    console.log('changeSorBy()!', values)
    this.fetchClients(searchParams)
  }

  handleSortDirection = (values = {}) => {
    const { sortBy, sortDirection, query } = this.props
    values.onSortByChange = values.onSortByChange
    values.onSortDirectionChange = values.onSortDirectionChange
      const searchParams = {
        query,
        sortBy,
        sortDirection,
        ...values,
        currentPage: 1,
      }
      console.log('changeSortDirection()!', values)
      this.fetchClients(searchParams)
    }
```

**Problem**
User clicks on the first column and it re-renders sorted on that column. It also displays glyphicon icon next to column header for direction of sort. This works and is bourne out by the console.logs below.

```
changeSorBy()! Object {onSortByChange: "ClientNumber", onSortDirectionChange: "Ascending"}
ClientsContainer.jsx:32 fetchClients()! Object {currentPage: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", sortBy: "ClientNumber", sortDirection: "Ascending"…}
reducer.js:19 queryString values! Object {page: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", 
sortBy: "ClientNumber", sortDirection: "Ascending"}
reducer.js:43 reducer.queryString()! ?
page=1&pageSize=10&query=&sortBy=ClientNumber&sortDirection=Ascending
```

When I click on the glyphicon icon to change direction the child of the child is called however suddenly sortBy becomes an object and now nothing equates since its now testing against an object and not a string..

Here is the consol.logs for clicking on the icon.. notice that now sortBy is an object instead of say "ClientNumber"...

```
changeSortDirection()! Object {onSortDirectionChange: "Descending", onSortByChange: Object}
ClientsContainer.jsx:32 fetchClients()! Object {currentPage: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", sortBy: "ClientNumber", sortDirection: "Ascending"…}
reducer.js:19 queryString values! Object {page: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", sortBy: Object, sortDirection: "Descending"}
reducer.js:43 reducer.queryString()! ?page=1&pageSize=10&query=&sortBy=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&sortDirection=Descending
TableHeaders.jsx:47 TableHeaders()! Object {sortBy: "ClientNumber"} Descending
TableHeaders.jsx:53 SortBy() before onClick Object {sortBy: "ClientNumber"}
TableHeaders.jsx:55 SortBy() sortDirection()! Object {sortBy: "ClientNumber"} Descending
```

The query string now has "%5Bobject%20Object%5D&" instead of "ClientNumber"..

Could someone explain to me why it becomes an object and also how can I fix and also avoid it in the future?

**EDIT**

I made the changes that Ollim suggested. The various Console.Logs show that both "sortBy" and "sortDirection" are both undefined.

```
changeSorBy()! Object {sortBy: "ClientNumber", sortDirection: "Ascending", onSortByChange: undefined, onSortDirectionChange: undefined}
ClientsContainer.jsx:32 fetchClients()! Object {currentPage: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", sortBy: "ClientNumber", sortDirection: "Ascending"…}
reducer.js:19 queryString values! Object {page: 1, pageSize: 10, query: "", sortBy: undefined, sortDirection: undefined}
reducer.js:43 reducer.queryString()! ?page=1&pageSize=10&query=
```

As I mentioned I am a beginner at this but I would have thought that you cannot change props as they are state and state is immutable. These are constants. That was why I had used separate variables that were not constants and then used those  as part of the values that I would set the query with..

Answer (score 1):

In TableHeader:

```
<span onClick={() => onSortByChange({onSortByChange:'ClientNumber', onSortDirectionChange: 'Ascending'})}>Client # </span>
```

should probably be

```
<span onClick={() => onSortByChange({sortBy:'ClientNumber', sortDirection: 'Ascending'})}>Client # </span>
```

Also in your handlers, you seem to have code that does nothing:

```
values.onSortByChange = values.onSortByChange
values.onSortDirectionChange = values.onSortDirectionChange
```

Comment: I have posted an EDIT which tried this.  I think the problem is in GlyphiconDirectionChange and where I set onSortByChange to {sortBy}. its here that onSortByChange is set to an object not a string....